# Toggle between categories and sub categories within the same div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parent div called `container`. Within that div is a main category nav called `togglelinks`. This toggles between the div class within `categories` called `people`, there are about 5 per category e.g. `people`, `business` etc. I have only shown the code for `people` below.

So with div class `people` are  multiple divs with IDs. The landing one will be `people`. Within the div with id "people" is multiple li links that link to div IDs outside the div ID `people` e.g. `business` and `highlife`. So when a link within id "people" is clicked then it hides ID `people` and shows ID `business` as an example. The rest of the structure I will figure out, its just this part I am struggling with.

Basic (simplified) structure below:

```
<div class="people">
 <div id="people">
  <ul>

   <li>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#business">
    <span>Business</span>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/business.jpg" alt="Category People" />
    </a>
   </li>

   <li>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="#highlife">
    <span>Highlife</span>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/highlife.jpg" alt="Category Highlife" />
    </a>
   </li>

  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="business">
 </div>

 <div id="highlife">
 </div>

</div>
```

Below is jQuery I have tried:

```
jQuery("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
    var selector = jQuery(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
    jQuery("div").hide();
    jQuery(selector).show();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you want to do.

The fiddle navigates through people, business and highlife showing one section at at time.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C9kF3/)

```
   jQuery("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
       var target = $(this).data('toggle');
       $('.people > div').hide();
       $('.people ' + target).fadeIn();
   });
```

Comment: It should work on this site: http://zero.rosewaterstudios.com/, but it is not working, no errors. Just not working, i am no jquery expert. I have no clue why its not working. Could you look by any chance for me please. Your script works great and its exactly what i need.

Comment: Just had a quick look at your page. It's possible that your slider plugin CSS interferes or maybe the markup is not right. I will try to have a look later today but can't promise anything.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get it working fine now, thanks alot! it was a small error with the document handler closing brackets. But now I realize I need to extend this code abit. Maybe you could help me out here, shouldn't be a huge change. Needs one more higher level: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamsynk/q5jD8/4/

Comment: UPDATED Link: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamsynk/q5jD8/5/ togglelinks takes you back to the parent div e.g. people