# jQuery not working outside jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have another question asked, a user answered it perfectly and his code is exactly what I need, tested and working on jsFiddle. But now as soon as I copy past it all outside jsFiddle it just doesnt work. My jQuery is very poor.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9kF3/

The script is below and also in jsFiddle above:

```
jQuery("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
   var target = $(this).data('toggle');
   $('.people > div').hide();
   $('.people ' + target).fadeIn();
});
```

I copy pasted it exactly as it is in that fiddle, didn't change a thing. No errors showing in console, the script just doesn't work. I linked to latest jquery library: code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js.

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you used [__document-ready__](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler? Wrap that code in `$( document ).ready(function() { ....
});`

Comment: No errors thats the thing

Comment: http://zero.rosewaterstudios.com - staging link, on the right are dots, the second dota "portfolio" is where the script is being applied.

Comment: have you used document handler??

Comment: are you adding `data-toggle` anchors dynamically (like using ajax call)?

Comment: Thanks, I did wrap it but apparently this is what was breaking it }));, one bracket to many. Was not giving an error for this. Thanks guys, such a silly mistake.

Comment: Happy to hear that your problem is solved now. However questions about problems caused by a __simple typographical error__ are __off-topic__ on SO. Please consider deleting this question by yourself.

Comment: Then you should have had a syntax error. Anyway please do some further reading of the jQuery docs. You have this in your code: `jQuery(document).ready(jQuery(function (){ `, `jQuery([...])` returns and jQuery result set containing one element (the document). Passing this as parameter to `jQuery(document).ready([...])` has no effect, so you could remove that wrapping `jQuery(document).ready()`. The   `jQuery([callback])`  is the same as `jQuery(document).ready([callback])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in separate `.js` file and wrapped in:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //your code here
});
```

After, link this file inside **`<head>`** tag

Comment: Thanks, I had it wrapped in document handler, mistake was at closing e.g. })); had one bracket to many.

Comment: Putting it at the and of his document, directly before `</body>` would be way better. Because the DOM gets loaded and if that is finished, the JavaScript gets loaded.

Comment: That's true, but sometimes it's better inside head (depending when you need it loads)

Comment: @Mark Won't matter when you're using document ready, it won't actually do anything earlier then it would, included in the bottom of body? morkro is right, bottom of body is better.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have a document ready wrapper around your jQuery code. Second, that feels like a lot of unnecessary code for what you're trying to accomplish. Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/C9kF3/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="people">
        <a href="#">People</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Business</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Highlife</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#people {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $('ul#navigation li a').click(function() {

        var self = $(this).closest('li'),
            navigation = self.closest('ul#navigation');

        $('ul#navigation li').not(self).show();
        self.hide();

        navigation.hide().fadeIn();

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, will use it.

Comment: Where is the original question regarding this and I will post the answer there as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955295/toggle-between-catagories-and-sub-catagories-within-the-same-div